# Hadoop (HDFS) for images storing

Tags: hadoop, distribution, hdfs, cluster-computing

I encountered lately with the well-known software-stack called "Hadoop".
Hadoop supply a distributed file system called HDFS.

now, what I need is a system to store mass of images and other media-files
read actions > write actions.
I need also reliability, fall-back solution and *performance*.

I understood that HDFS got the answers for my needs.
do you think Hadoop (with HDFS) is the right solution for me?

thanks in advanced.
SockSocket

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2278186/storing-images-in-nosql-stores

Comment: Like the answer in the other thread I'd suggest MongoDB.

Answer (score 0):

hdfs can serve the purpose..if you want to store your data more systematically you can use Hbase(a column family oriented database based on Google's Bigtable).