# NoSQL- Is it suitable for storing images?

Tags: database, image, nosql, distributed-computing, fault-tolerance

I would like to store millions of images using a distributed fault tolerant system. While storing images in relational database has never been recommended, I was wondering if it is a suitable approach to store and manage image files in NoSQL databases.

I would appreciate if you could share your experience in details here. (i.e. what NoSQL database did you use? it's advantages and disadvantages in this case, etc)

Thanks

Comment: search much?: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2278186/storing-images-in-nosql-stores

Comment: Yeah we do a lot of search on the images. Couldn't find my answer in that thread.

Comment: I think the most reliable way to do this is by using a SQL database where you only store paths to your images. Why don't you want to use one ?

Comment: @user2154283 I was thinking of using a fault tolerant database to reduce the risk of loosing my data. Also we are planning to perform some sort of encryption on the images so they are accessible only through our application. I thought these both can be achieved by storing images in a NoSQL database.

Comment: @Arash When it comes to data safety, I would rather trust an enterprise-grade storage-area-network with high-level RAID and redundant backups than an experimental NoSQL database.

Comment: Why do you want to store the image in the database?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

MongoDB has an API called [GridFS](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/gridfs/) which was made for storing binary files on the database cluster.

But just as with relational databases, storing files in a filesystem on a [SAN](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Storage_area_network) is often a faster, more efficient, more maintainable and safer alternative.

Comment: In MongoDB, use GridFS for storing files larger than 16 MB