# Storing Images / Media Files in Oracle

Tags: oracle, image, media

I want to store a large number of media files in oracle. I believe I can store these files in the form of blobs using pl/sql procedure. However I want to make sure there is no impact to resolution / quality of the media file. Also are there any considerations that I need to account for to store media files in Oracle DB?

Comment: http://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/150669/is-it-a-bad-practice-to-store-large-files-10-mb-in-a-database

Answer (score 3):

By storing and retrieving files in a blob does not impact image quality or resolution. Oracle does treat them as binary objects and what you store is what you get when you retrieve.

Typically such modifications are done at application layer logic before storing data into blob. In case of text based files, compressing them and storing them would save some disk space, in case of images, typically resolution/image size is modified to reduce file size etc. These are the decisions taken while designing application, as part of application architecture to reduce overall storage requirement.

Also, consider if this is going to be right design for you. There are implications in terms of storage requirement, application performance and scalablity. There are several threads in stackoverflow discussing advantages of storing images in RDBMS vs NoSQL databases vs filesystems. Also average size of files do matter a lot.

some links:

[Storing images in NoSQL stores](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2278186/storing-images-in-nosql-stores)

[NoSQL- Is it suitable for storing images?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18819292/nosql-is-it-suitable-for-storing-images)

[Storing very big files in database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18300153/storing-very-big-files-in-database)

https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/150669/is-it-a-bad-practice-to-store-large-files-10-mb-in-a-database