# hadoop on windows, how to add D:\folder1 and E:\folder1 to hdfs?

Tags: hadoop

```
hadoop fs -put popularNames.txt /user/hadoop/dir1/popularNames.txt
```

My folders are very huge, about 3 TB.
I don't want to copy the folder, I want to set the hdfs to the location. How to make it?

Comment: Set hdfs to that location? What is that supposed to mean?

Comment: The old big folder `D:\folder1 and E:\folder1 ` just make hdfs save on  `D:\folder1 and E:\folder1 `

Comment: No it has to be on the hdfs to use hadoop features. Otherwise you are just having the file in you local and hadoop can't run a map/reduce job or maintain replication, etc..

Comment: Thanks! My files are all images resource. I don't need map reduce, I only want to visit,save and delete them. Can you have better idea to make it? @AniMenon

Comment: Use a database. Not hdfs. [Check this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2278186/storing-images-in-nosql-stores)

Comment: You don´t need MapReduce, You don´t need to move your files, then What are you really asking for ?

Answer (score 1):

HDFS: Hadoop distributed file system.

You can't add a link to point to a location, because the data must be present in the HDFS(not on local). The whole point of using hadoop is distributed computation, which is possible when your data is distributed on a cluster.

`hadoop fs -put` had to be used to move the file from your local to the hdfs in order to use hadoop framework.

Comment: But I don't want to move or copy, because the disk capacity is too small to copy. And the older folder is used by old software system. Can I just `hadoop fs -put` and make hdfs save on the folder's old location ?

Comment: @Gank no the file had to reside on the hdfs for you to utilize the hadoop framework which includes the map reduce and all the other features.

Comment: Thanks! My files are all images resource. I don't need map reduce, I only want to visit,save and delete them. Can I make it?

Comment: You need a database, not hdfs.