# How to insert image in mysql and display it in vb?

Tags: mysql, vb.net, xampp

I am working with my project and i need to insert pictures in each data. My problem is how can i put pictures in my database using xampp as my back end.

Comment: I do not recommend storing large blobs in a RDMS, I recommend you use a noSQL DB instead. Take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2278186/storing-images-in-nosql-stores

Answer (score 0):

@Nico_robin, Please do not insert IMAGE in your MySQL Database, It is a bad practice!!!
What you can do is to save the Images in you server possibly in your images folder / User upload folder.
Save the image path( file/folder name) in your column. That's one of the better ways.

In your usecase If it is a Hard requirement to save images in DB then try using LONGBLOB or MEDIUMBLOB

Also Check this URL [Storing image in database directly or as base64 data?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9722603/storing-image-in-database-directly-or-as-base64-data)